# How can i run a .exe-file with batch?

Tags: windows-xp, batch

first off: i've been making batch-files before, but this time (i don't know how or why) I've got stuck with something simple. So I'm trying to make a program which starts a virtual disc and opens a game afterwards. Could you guys please help me? What is wrong with my program?

```
 @echo off
title Diablo Starter
color 4a

:start
cls
echo (D)iablo / Diablo (L)oD
set /p choose=Was soll ausgefuehrt werden?   
if %choose%==d goto simple
if %choose%==D goto simple
if %choose%==l goto exp
if %choose%==L goto exp
echo Bitte geben Sie entweder 'D' oder 'L' ein.
pause
goto start

:simple
cls
start "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\User\Desktop\Hauptordner\Diablo II + LoD\2. PLAY DISC.ISO"
@ping -n 4 localhost> nul
start "C:\Programme\Diablo II\Diablo II.exe"
exit

:exp
cls
start "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\User\Desktop\Hauptordner\Diablo II + LoD\4. EXPANSION DISC.ISO"
@ping -n 4 localhost> nul
start "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\User\Startmenü\Programme\Diablo II\Diablo II - Lord of Destruction"
```

Comment: If you tell us where it is going wrong we might be able to help ...

Comment: Oh sorry. Pfff, im useless today. The problem is that when it comes to the part where it should start the game, it just opens a cmd prompt with the path of the exe, as directory

Comment: Please edit your question instead of submitting commentary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Where it should start the game, it just opens a cmd prompt with the path of the exe

Please read the syntax for `start`.

You have the program name in quotes (which are required because the program name contains spaces) but `start` interprets this as the window title.

Provide an empty title string as follows:

```
start "" "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\User\Desktop\Hauptordner\Diablo II + LoD\4. EXPANSION DISC.ISO".
```

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like "My Script" or
>   just a pair of empty quotes ""
>
> According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but
>   depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is
>   omitted.

Source - [Start - Start a program - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Start - Start a program - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)